# Websites running very slow

Tags: html, mysql, linux, apache, webserver

we have a vserver problem that started all of the sudden yesterday.
If you go to this Website:

http://www.rightsfreeradio.de

You will notice that it needs ages to load.

This happends to **all websites** we have running on the vserver.
I was asking the Provider if there is any problem with their connections, but they dont have any problems.

**If I log in to FTP its running fast as usual**
only all web based applications and websites are running very slow.

Running "top" shows that mysql takes like 70%+ on the CPU, but Iam not sure if thats normal or not.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong with the server?

Answer (score 0):

What programming standards are you using. I opened link but did not open it.

Either there may issue with server. Or another cas is:

1. Check any js, css file taking time to load
2. Put unncessary imported files at the end of body tag
3. On load are you calling any function which may be prone to deadlock getting blocked?

Comment: well I dont think it is this website wich has errors, we have problems with ALL websites.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to use HTML Validator to correct your HTML etc.
2. Also make sure all scripts are working fine or to debug. Take off all the script files imported and go from there.
3. Link doesn't open at all.

Comment: website worked fine till yesterday. if you wait 10 minutes, you see the website is loading, but realy slowly and thats the problem. But it happnd to all our websites.

Comment: Try killing all the processes in the webserver. See if that takes the load of the server. If all your websites are loading slow, it has to do with your webserver

Answer (score 0):

first, I suggest you to restart all service on your server and then:

1. check mysql error log as you say above

   tail -f /var/log/mysql.log
2. and then, check your databases

   mysqlcheck -Aor
3. and you can follow this link bellow

[Show top five CPU consuming processes with `ps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/show-top-five-cpu-consuming-processes-with-ps)